# Add a Non-Model field only for post method on ModelSerializer DRF3

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to add a custom field that will only be used while creating an object. For example, I have a model serializer and I want to add that field that doesn't present in my model and I want to use this only while `post` request.

Model:

```
class Ship(BaseModel):
    capacity = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    mother_ship = models.ForeignKey(MotherShip, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Serializer:

```
class ShipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Ship
        fields = ('id', 'mother_ship')
```

How I want:

```
class ShipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     count = serializers.SomeMagicalField() # only for post methods
    class Meta:
        model = models.Ship
        fields = ('id', 'mother_ship')
```

Comment: Can you show your model/serializer and how you want to use this field?

Comment: updated the post, please do take another look.

Answer (score 0):

There are serverals ways to achieve it, something easy is to create two serializer and in APIView implement the `get_serializer()` method, share the following example:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if not self.request.POST:
        return ShipSerializerPOST
    return ShipSerializer
```

The first solution can be applied when the serializers have big diferences.

In your case the diference is so small that you can use the second option that I share in the following example:

```
class ShipSerializer():
    count = serializers.SomeMagicalField() # only for post methods
    class Meta:
        model = models.Ship
        fields = ('id', 'mother_ship')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Don't return count if POST
        if not self.request.POST:
            del self.fields['count']

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Hope one of the options helps.